# URL for facebook?

Tags: ios, facebook

Can I know the code for facebook application? for example https://www.facebook.com/nike/?fref=ts .. I tried it bit it didn't work. I tried it with the youtube code but it didn't work!

For example for youtube

```
-(IBAction)btnYoutube:(id)sender {

        NSURL *linkToAppURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"youtube://user/%@",@"toyotaleasing"]];
        NSURL *linkToWebURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/user/%@",@"toyotaleasing"]];

        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:linkToAppURL]) {
            // Can open the youtube app URL so launch the youTube app with this URL
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:linkToAppURL];
        }
        else{
            // Can't open the youtube app URL so launch Safari instead
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:linkToWebURL];
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know?

Comment: did you try below solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the log in console it will show below log :

**-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "youtube://user/toyotaleasing" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme youtube"**

The solution is, you need to "whitelist" all your URL schemes which will be used in your app, list down in info.plist.

info.plist key for this is "**LSApplicationQueriesSchemes**".

This is how your info.plist look like when you add "youtube" as scheme.

[image]

Now it will work.